# Lock Dictionary in python

Tags: c#, python, c#-4.0, dictionary, locking

I am new to python and just migrated from C#. I am working on a project which has multi user support. In our project we have common dictionaries which are filled with data from database when the application starts. Now these dictionaries are used to display data on UI of various forms. So if one user edits data on the UI the other user logged in also sees the change. I want to know if there is a locking mechanism in python that prevents simultaneous access of objects as in C#

Comment: http://effbot.org/zone/thread-synchronization.htm

Comment: What do you mean by 'as in C#'? Is there something special, is there something you expect?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is an equivalent for locking in Python. You can use a get method and don't provide a set method. Have the dictionary load when the application starts. If this is for Python 3, then you can use a static method, see [link](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#how-do-i-create-static-class-data-and-static-class-methods).